# How do I load content from a server into jQuerymobile pages?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, mobile

I am working on an app that uses jQuerymobile elements to make the UI.

It runs smoothly and everything but I want to load content from a server rather than load them up locally.

Currently my app has usual iOS files + HTMLs which make the app UI up and have buttons that execute commands. (This app will only work on jailbroken iDevices).

The problem is that I don't want to link to a locally stored file that can be tweaked... I am trying to make the app as secure as possible as it will contain direct links to data that I cannot risk giving out even if some people don't know how the app works.

How do I make it so that a button will load a page from a site ex. domain.com/html

Comment: would ajax call work for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a request with the server URL and load the request in UIWebView.